# Flask Oauth2 get Google+ profile-picture-url from the profile-picture-json

Tags: json, api, flask, google-plus, oauth-2.0

I have a problem here in obtaining the Google+ profile-picture-url from the profile-picture-json. I'm quite a beginner and this is my first webapp so please take this into account.

My callback function:

```
def callback(self):
    self.validate_oauth2callback()
    oauth_session = self.service.get_auth_session(
            data={'code': request.args['code'],
                  'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
                  'redirect_uri': self.get_callback_url()
                 },
            decoder=jsondecoder
    )
    me = oauth_session.get('').json()
    social_id = 'google$' + me['sub']
    username = me.get('name', None) if me.get('name', None) else me['email'].split('@')[0]
    email = me['email'] if me['email_verified'] == True else None
    url = me.get('profile', None)
    image_json = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/' + me['sub'] + '?fields=image&key=AIz..yAl..juCqj..sjj9y..PuM..R..9..F8p..mo'
    image = image_json['image'] # <-- THIS DOESN'T WORK
    return social_id, username, email, url, image, me
```

My problem is that the variable `image_json` contains the following:

```
{
 "image": {
  "url": "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-f..i0..dl..Gc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABQ/iNw-IEz...o/photo.jpg?sz=50",
  "isDefault": false
 }
}
```

and I have to extract the profile-picture-url from that. A substring method doesn't work since in order to get that code I have to "run" the url saved in `image_json`.
What I need is something like `image = image_json['image']` to retrieve the string:

`"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-f..i0..dl..Gc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABQ/iNw-IEz...o/photo.jpg?sz=50"`

and I would like to change that size in 256 instead of 50.
I have followed many posts but I didn't found a solution for this thing.

The view that will call this function is the following:

```
@auth.route('/callback/<provider>')
def oauth_callback(provider):
    oauth = OAuthSignIn.get_provider(provider)
    social_id, username, email, url, image, jsonme = oauth.callback()

    if social_id is None:  
        flash('Authentication failed! Access to ' + provider + ' denied.')
        return redirect(url_for('main.home'))

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

    if not user:  
        user = User(social_id=social_id, username=username, email=email, social_page=url, social_image=image)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

    else:  

       ...

    login_user(user, True)
    return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but it seems like you're very close to what you need.  Why not use `image = image_json['image']['url']`?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error:           
 image = image_json['image']['url']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Actually it doesn't work because the variable `image_json` is not containing  a dictionary but just the string `'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/111111111111111?fields=image&key=AIz..yAl..juCqj..sjj9y..PuM..R..9..F8p..mo'` for this reason i need something like a "decoder" which can get the body of the page, because that dictionary is in the body not in the url

Comment: Ok, I get that part now.  How are you going from that URL to the JSON object you show in your question?  Based on your code snippet, I'm only seeing you storing the URL as a string in `image_json`.

Comment: ok I have edit my initial question in such a way that you can understand what is my objective. I need the link to the profile picture because I want to store in my database the user created obtaining his information from his Google account. In this way the user can login into my webapp without registering in the traditional way. He just push the button 'Sign in with Google' and he become a registered user with all his parameters taken from his Google account. Everything works except the profile picture because I'm not able to obtain the google-profile-picture-url (but I'm close to achieve it)

Comment: What does `me['sub']` contain?

Comment: it contains the unique id that google assigns to the user. It is the primary_key  in the table of Users for this reason I am using it in my own database, i just attach the 'google$' substring before.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have solved using simply `image = me['picture']`, the variable `image_json` is no longer required.